# multicolumn tocloft TOC assigning subsection to wrong section

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, xcookybooky

I've been compiling a number of recipes as a cookbook.

I've used the package xcookybooky to compile recipes and have assembled them in the main tex. I'm trying to use tocloft to create a multicolumn table of contents, which works mostly. In the TOC I'm creating sections that don't show up on their own page, but just in the TOC. Weirdly enough it seems though, that the last subsection is always wrongly carried over to the next section. Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution yet.

Specifically, in Overleaf part of the source looks like this:

[image]

In the compiled document though, it is displayed like this:

[image]

The commands used in the individual recipes are provided by the package [xcookybooky](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcookybooky?lang=en) and are handled in subfiles. The package seems to automatically create a subsection for each recipe added.

A minimal example demonstrating the behaviour can be found [here](https://github.com/DarioRomano/Mamas-Kochbuch-Overleaf/blob/MWE-bug/main.tex).

The code for the main document would be:

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
twoside,
11pt
]{extarticle} 

% encoding, font, language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\usepackage{}
\usepackage[light]{CormorantGaramond}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
 
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{-40pt}

\usepackage[
    nowarnings,
]
{xcookybooky}

\cftpagenumbersoff{section}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcelcius}{\ensuremath{^{\circ}\mathrm{C}}}
 \setHeadlines{
    inghead = Zutaten,
    prephead = Zubereitung,
    hinthead=Tipp,
    continuationhead= Fortsetzung,
    continuationfoot= 
    }

    \setRecipenameFont{ %pbsi % fau % fwb % fjd 
     % default
    }{T1}{m}{n}
    
    \definecolor{MyOrange}{RGB}{255, 191, 0}
    \definecolor{MyOrange2}{RGB}{255, 128, 0}
    
    \setRecipeColors
    {% initialisation
     recipename= black,
     hinthead=black,
     hintline=MyOrange
    }
    
    \setRecipeSizes
    {
        recipename= \fontsize{25pt}{1pt}
    }
    \setRecipeLengths{
        preparationwidth=0.5\textwidth,
        ingredientswidth=0.4\textwidth,
    }

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand*{\recipesection}[2][]
{%
    \subsection[#1]{#2}
}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]
{% no implementation to display the section name instead
}


\usepackage{hyperref}    % must be the last package
\hypersetup{%
    pdfauthor            = {Von Dario und Sulgie},
    pdftitle             = {Rezeptbuch Beate},
    pdfsubject           = {Recipes},
    pdfkeywords          = {example, recipes, cookbook, xcookybooky},
    pdfstartview         = {FitV},
    pdfview              = {FitH},
    pdfpagemode          = {UseNone}, % Options; UseNone, UseOutlines
    bookmarksopen        = {true},
    pdfpagetransition    = {Glitter},
    colorlinks           = {true},
    linkcolor            = {black},
    urlcolor             = {blue},
    citecolor            = {black},
    filecolor            = {black},
}

\hbadness=10000 % Ignore underfull boxes
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
%\vspace{5em}


\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Eingemachtes}{}
    \include{tex/Bärlauchpesto}
   
    

\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Gebäck}{}
    \include{tex/Bierbrötchen}
    \include{tex/Stangenweißbrot}
\end{document}
```

The included documents all have the same layout. An example for one of them would be:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}


\begin{figure}[!t]
\vspace*{-3.3cm}
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-\oddsidemargin-1in}{-\rightmargin}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{pic/bierbrötchen.jpg}
   \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\begin{recipe}
{Bierbrötchen}


    \ingredients
    {% Zutaten
        \unit[350]{g} & Roggenmehl\\
        \unit[200]{g}& Weizenmehl\\
        \unit[1]{Flasche}& Bier\\
        \unit[1]{Pkg.}& Backpulver\\
        \unit[1]{Prise} & Salz\\
        etwas & Kümmel
    }
    
   \preparation{
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,labelwidth=\itemindent,itemindent=.5cm]
    \item Mehl, Backpulver und Salz in einer Schüssel mischen. Bier langsam zugießen und dabei verkneten. Nur soviel Bier zufügen, bis sich der Teig vom Schüsselrand löst.
    \item Teig in kleine Teile schneiden oder reißen und zu Brötchen formen
    \item Nach Belieben zusätzlich mit grobem Salz und Kümmel bestreuen.
    \item Bei 150°C ca. 30 Minuten backen.
    \end{enumerate}
    }
 

\end{recipe}

\end{otherlanguage}
```

Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making, or could this be a bug in xcookybooky?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All you have shown is that you have used `\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Geback}{}`. We have no idea what else you have done except include some unknown files. Perhaps the problem is with those or any of the other code you have not shown. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question with links to the corresponding files, and have provided a link to a smaller version of the project using only 3 included files to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: This site does not like external links as they can disappear and the site wants everything to always be available. Provide the MWE code, not links.

Comment: @PeterWilson I've added the code of the main document for the MWE, and an example for one of the included files. Since the contents are structurally identical, just changing the title to a couple different included documents should create the same behaviour.

Comment: I have no time to try, but my guess would be: don't use \include but \input. Or move the `\cftaddtitleline{toc}{section}{Eingemachtes}{}` into the included file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A first try in the MWE with `\input` seems to work, although I have to create additional `\newpage` entries, or else the images become bugged. I will try it with the full document later. If you write a full answer, I could also award you the bounty in case that works.